# How to fill in this HashMap neatly without code duplication?

Tags: java

I'm supplying a HashMap with data in the following way:

```
HashMap<String,MyClass> myHashMap = new HashMap<String,MyClass>();
myHashMap.put( "foo", new MyClass(2,4) );
myHashMap.put( "bar", new MyClass(0,10) );
myHashMap.put( "a",   new MyClass(0,0) );
myHashMap.put( "b",   new MyClass(0,1) );
myHashMap.put( "c",   new MyClass(0,0) );
myHashMap.put( "d",   new MyClass(0,42) );
// ...
```

There's around 20 lines, but a lot is duplicated text. The only interesting information in every line is foo,2,4, bar,0,10, a,0,0 and so on. How can I make this code neater?

If only the strings differed, I'd do it this way:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.aslist("foo","bar","a","b","c","d");
for ( String name : names )
    myHashMap.put( name, new MyClass(0,0) );
```

Comment: I don't think that there is enough information to offer a good alternative. What are the values "foo", 2, 4, etc? Where does the data originate (for both keys and values)? How are keys and values related (if at all)? How will the Map be used after it is created?

Comment: The data is hard-coded business logic. Each instance of MyClass represents a parameter with scaling factors and maximum values. Since the class doesn't do much except collect them, it makes more sense to put those values there than in a separate file.

Comment: i feel the first set of code is ok, because it is readable, understandable to any coder in team(or future members), and maintainable. [which does not need extra documentation for the code!].

Comment: The first set of code is fine, but it does not lend itself to optimization as it is not clear why it is doing what it is doing. For example, are the keys arbitrary - is a Map needed at all or could a Set be used? Would the Key be better represented as a property of `MyClass`? If reading the values from an external source, would an iterator be preferable? Will the map be modified post creation (is it static?)?

Comment: You considered putting these into easily-editable configuration files? That does add another class to parse that file and create a HashMap, but might leader to better abstraction (easy to swap them out at runtime is a bonus).

Answer (score 1):

Then I would use a static method to put the entries in the map:

```
HashMap<String,MyClass> myHashMap = new HashMap<String,MyClass>();
addEntry(myHashMap, "foo",2,4);
addEntry(myHashMap, "bar", 0,10);
addEntry(myHashMap, "a", 0,0);
addEntry(myHashMap, "b", 0,1);
addEntry(myHashMap, "c", 0,0);
addEntry(myHashMap, "d", 0,42);
// ...

private static //
void addEntry(HashMap<String,MyClass> map, String name, int arg1, int arg2){
  map.put( name, new MyClass(arg1,arg2) );
}
```

I recommend reading the data from a file and call `addEntry(myHashMap, ...);` in a loop until end of file is reached.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way (but maybe not the best looking one), is this:

```
String[] names = new String[]{"foo","bar","a","b","c","d"};
int[] parameter1 = new int[]{2,0,0,0,0,0};
int[] parameter2 = new int[]{4,10,0,1,0,42};

for (int i=0; names.length>i; i++)
    myHashMap.put( names[i], new MyClass(parameter1[i],parameter2[i]) );
```

If they are a lot of entries, you should consider to put the names and the parameters in an external file and read that instead of putting this information in your source code. [**Putting the data to a file is my recommendation**]

or also a bit ugly:

```
Object[] data = new String[]{"foo", 2, 4, // 
                             "bar", 0,10, // 
                             "a", 0,0, // 
                             "b", 0,1, // 
                             "c", 0,0, // 
                             "d" 0,42,
                            };
int i=0;
while (data.length>i)
    myHashMap.put( (String)data[i++], new MyClass((Integer)data[i++],(Integer)data[i++]) );
```

Comment: I think it would be difficult to see e.g. that (b,0,1) belong together.

Comment: @Andreas: I added another possibility which allows better to see, what belongs together.

Comment: Wouldn't using a new line instead of `/**/` be a better way of formatting?

Comment: @Bobby: Yes, but my impression was that Andreas wanted less lines of code than his initial approach. Formatting is most times a matter of taste.

Comment: I'm not looking for less lines, but rather less cruft and text that doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Bobby: I changed the second variant of my answer to a easier to read formatting.

Comment: @MrSmith42: May I suggest a small tweak? Remove the `//` and start with the data on a new line, indented by one step [like this](http://pastebin.com/YRnUrrSG). This way the array creates a "visual block" of it's own (similar to if/for-blocks). The declaration is also incorrect, it should be Object, not String, and the last line has messed up commas.

Comment: @Bobby: The `//` avoids my IDE (eclipse) to merge the line together.

Comment: @MrSmith42: Oh, that one. It's one of these thing I need to remember to turn off when using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class?

```
class MyHashMapCreator {
  private HashMap<String, MyClass> myHashMap = new HashMap<String,MyClass>();
  public MyBuilder add(String x, int y, int z) {
     myHashMap.add(x, new MyClass(y, z));
  }
  public HashMap<String, MyClass> getHashMap() {
    return myHashMap;
  }
}
```

And use it like...

```
HashMap<String,MyClass> hashmap = new MyHashMapCreator().
    add("foo", 2, 4).
    add("bar", 0, 10).
    add("a", 0, 0).
    add("b", 0, 1).
    add("c", 0, 0).
    add("d", 0, 42).getHashMap();
```

Although its odd that you have the data in your class and from an external source (service? database?)

Comment: The data is business logic. Each instance of MyClass represents a parameter with scaling factors and maximum values. Since the class doesn't do much except collect them, it makes more sense to put those values there than in a separate file.

Comment: @Andreas, except that now you need a developer to change that file, if the data was external then an analyst could change it.

Comment: Will not the new class create extra overhead? in any case the "add" is going to to be repeated...

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure how to answer because I don't understand the use case, but here are a couple of thoughts.

If you are defining some data that will never change and is well understood then you could consider using an enum:

```
public enum ParamterScale {
    X(2, 4),
    Y(2, 4),
    LENGTH(0, 10);

    private int scale;
    private int maximum;

    private ParameterScale(int scale, int maximum) {
        this.scale = scale;
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }

    //getters
}
```

By using an enum you clearly enumerate all the supported cases and encapsulate your data without resorting to data structures that do not fit your purpose.

If your data is not clearly defined, or is dynamic or extensible in anyway then the enum approach will not work. At this point I would need to understand the relationship between the key and value in your map. If the key describes the parameter and the two values encapsulate the behavior then the key should be a part of the `MyClass` object (if this is the case you are using `MyClass` as a tuple). In this case you should begin by modifying `MyClass` to include a parameterName member variable and then override `equals` and `hashCode` so that you can use `MyClass` in a set. How you chose to override the methods will depend on whether you can have multiple instances of a parameter with different values or whether each parameter name should be unique.

If your data is hardcoded today, but might not be tomorrow, don't worry about it. If your data is hardcoded today and won't be tomorrow you could define an interface, say `ParameterValueProvider`. This interface can expose whatever maethods might be useful to you - size, iterator, next... Create a single implementation for today say `StaticParameterDataProvider` or `MockParameterDataProvider` - whatever accurately describes the data you will be feeding back. This means that in the future you could add a `CSVParameterDataProvider` or `XMLParameterDataProvider` or whatever.

Now, inside your `StaticParameterDataProvider` you could create an enum as described above. If you need to iterate over the values to convert them into another structure you can use the `.values` method:

```
for (ParameterScale ps : ParameterScale.values()) {
    //then for each value you can access it's fields like so.
    ps.name(); //or ps.toString() if you want to customise the parameter name
    ps.getScale();
    ps.getMaximum();
}
```

If the HashMap is important, you can use a static initialiser within an enum like this:

```
public enum ParameterScale {

    //enum values
    ...

    public static Map<String, MyClass> params;

    static {
        params = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
        for (ParameterScale ps : ParameterScale.values()) {
            params.put(ps.name(), new MyClass(ps.getScale(), ps.getMaximum()));
        }
    }

}
```

This is publicly accessible using `ParameterScale.params`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get any solution that will reduce you code drastically... but try [Double Brace Initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization).

```
HashMap<String,MyClass> myHashMap = new HashMap<String,MyClass>(){{
    put( "foo", new MyClass(2,4) );
    put( "bar", new MyClass(0,10) );
    put( "a"  , new MyClass(0,0) );
    put( "b"  , new MyClass(0,1) );
    put( "c"  , new MyClass(0,0) );
    put( "d"  , new MyClass(0,42) );
}};
```

Comment: Use it, or don't use it, but if you do, make sure you understand what it is doing and why it is better than the other options. One day someone will say WTF are all those braces up to :) This was a really interesting question on SO (don't worry about the efficiency angle, proably), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization

Comment: Double Brace Initialization is clever, but a bit deceptive: it doesn't create a normal HashMap, but rather an anonymous inner class that extends HashMap.